How to find a thread-safe collection in Java that enforces both uniqueness and size limits on insertion?
I’m looking for a thread-safe collection in Java that:

Enforces uniqueness of elements (like a Set).
Limits the size of the collection (rejects further insertions once the limit is reached).
Does this natively by default (without needing custom logic or wrapping another collection).

So far, I’ve considered:

ConcurrentSkipListSet for uniqueness, but it doesn’t have a size limit.
BlockingQueue for size control, but it doesn’t enforce uniqueness.
Custom implementations using ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet() for uniqueness and manually managing size.

Is there a standard Java thread-safe collection that provides both features (uniqueness and size limitation) without needing custom handling? Or do I need to implement my own solution?

I don't think there's any built-in class that does this.  I think your best bet is to make a custom version of a thread safe Set and just enforce the size limitation, which should be easy to do.

You might examine the third-party collections libraries: Eclipse Collections, Google Guava, and Apache Commons Collections.

if google cant find it then just write  a wrapper and move on? its not a very sought after feature its probably not released/ made it to open src as yet :)

Read the documentation of container in the Java's standard library, see if anything there matches your criteria, then come back with a specific question if you have a doubt.

this question does not fit stackover flow question requriements, do go thru the [faq] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

You have three problems

Uniqueness - use set for this
Thread safe - wrap the set with - Collections.synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)
Restrict size - try modifying the set to immutability  (this would indirectly limit further addition)


You can also use a concurrentHashmap (okay i know some will it's not a collection but it belongs to api of collections), or you can implement your own Set and make it thread safe, but in java library, there is no collection which is accurate to your description.

You can try this (tried using Java SE 17):
Integer [] ints = { 1, 2, 3 }; // substitute your own objects
Set<Integer> set1 = Set.of(ints);
System.out.println("set: " + set1);
set1.add(4); // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Set<Integer> set2 = Collections.synchronizedSet(set1);
System.out.println("set2: " + set2);
set2.add(4); // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Reference: static  Set of(E... elements)

This creates an unmodifiable set.  The wording of the question strongly suggests that the OP wants to be able to modify the set.  Insertion should only be rejected when the set reaches the limit.


Or do I need to implement my own solution?

Yes, you do need your own implementation.
Taking the advice in Comment by markspace, I wrote this class extending ConcurrentSkipListSet to limit its size by overriding the add methods in Java 23. We can ignore the addFirst & addLast methods as they are not supported by ConcurrentSkipListSet.
I am no expert in this, so use at your own risk.
package work.basil.example.collecting;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class LimitedSizeConcurrentSkipListSet < E > extends ConcurrentSkipListSet < E >
{
    private final Semaphore addingSemaphore = new Semaphore( 1 );
    private final int sizeLimit = 2 ;

    @Override
    public boolean add ( E e )
    {
        try
        {
            this.addingSemaphore.acquire();
            if( this.size() > this.sizeLimit ) throw new IllegalStateException("Size of set should never exceed its limit.");
            if( this.size() == this.sizeLimit ) return false;
            return super.add( e );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( ex );
        }
        finally
        {
            this.addingSemaphore.release( );
        }
    }
}

Example usage:
SequencedSet<LocalDate> dates = new LimitedSizeConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 1));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 1));

System.out.println( "dates = " + dates );
Assertions.assertEquals( 2 , dates.size( ) );

